# How to do in Powershell - Read String irrespective of the String Structure/Format/Style

Tags: powershell

I have a code script which is reading a String of a particular Structure/Format/Style. If the String structure gets changed the code is not able to read the String.
Is there a generic method to read String irrespective of its structure/format.

The code can read the string - **AnimalClass_AnimalType_64Animals_Whitezone_Local_x86.log 100.43**

But it fails to read the string such as
**AnimalClass_AnimalType_64Animals_Whitezone_Local_x86.log 100.43**

or

**AnimalClass-Animal-Type_64Animals_Whitezone_Local_x86.log 100.43**

Or

**Animal-Class-Animal-Type_64Animals_Whitezone_Local_x86.log 100.43**

The Code is (refer to the if condition)

```
function Import-Results
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$Path
    
  )

  # Read the file, line by line
  Get-Content -Path $Path |ForEach-Object {
    # Test that the line conforms to the expected format, grab the name and value
    if($_ -match '^([\w\.]+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*$'){
      # output a new object with the TestCase name and ExecutionTime value
      [pscustomobject]@{
        TestCase = $Matches[1]
        ExecutionTime = $Matches[2] -as [decimal]
        OriginalLine = $_
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

The solution was originally posted on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448037/how-to-do-in-powershell-compare-3-text-files-and-create-a-new-text-file-with-m?noredirect=1#comment122760940_69448037)

Comment: From the examples you give, it seems that the failing ones differ only in their use of a dash ('-'), so all you need to do is add that character to your regex.  e.g. change `^([\w\.]+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*$'` to `'^([-\w\.]+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*$'`

Comment: @boxdog thanks for the reply. Your suggestion has solved the problem.